# CSS zoom property behaves differently in FF

Tags: html, css, zooming

I want to make a slider which always fits 100% of the screen and is aligned to the center, no matter what the resolution. I want to do it with the zoom property and change it by Javascript.

So far I coded this

CSS:

```
#wrapper-slider{position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;z-index:7;display:block;  -moz-transform: scale(0.3); zoom:30%; -moz-transform-origin:0 0;}       
#container-slider {background:url('http://i48.tinypic.com/znpwm0.jpg') no-repeat; width:967px; height:800px; margin: 0 auto; text-align:center; display: block; position: relative;}    
#wrapper-slider .img {position:absolute;display:black;z-index:8;height:486px;width:758px; padding-left: 101px; padding-top: 94px; margin:0 auto; text-align: center;}
#wrapper-slider .img img {max-height: 487px; max-width:758px; margin:0 auto; display: block;}
#container-slider p {position: absolute; z-index: 20; color:#000000;}
#container-slider strong { line-height: 21px;}
#container-slider .add-to-basket {left:109px; bottom:24px;}
#container-slider .add-to-basket a {display: block; width:142px; height:36px; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; color: black;line-height: 34px;}
#container-slider .description {right: 112px; bottom:17px; width: 361px; height:76px; text-align:center; font-size:15px;}
#container-slider .details {right:492px; bottom:17px; width:188px; height:76px; text-align:center; font-size:15px;}
#container-slider .price {left:109px; bottom:72px; width:142px; text-align:center; font-size:24px; color: #FF6C00;}
#container-slider .left{left:395px;}
#container-slider .right{right:401px;}
#container-slider .arrow{width:80px; height: 80px; display:block; bottom:120px; position:absolute;z-index:10; text-indent: -10000000px;}
#container-slider .close{width:70px; height: 70px; display:block; top:25px; right:40px; position:absolute;z-index:10; text-indent: -10000000px;}
#container-black{position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;background:#000;z-index:6;}​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper-slider">
    <div id="container-slider">
        <a class="close" href="#" title="Zamknij podgląd">close</a>

        <div class="img">
            <img class="main" src="http://asset0.cbsistatic.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim/2012/08/15/35414204_620x433.jpg"/>
        </div>

        <a class="arrow left" title="Poprzedni produkt" href="#">Left</a>
        <a class="arrow right" title="Następny produkt" href="#">Right</a>

        <p class="price">390.00 PLN</p>
        <p class="add-to-basket"><a href="#">Dodaj do koszyka</a></p>

        <p class="details">
            <strong>Wymiary:</strong><br>
            100 x 50 cm<br>
            <strong>Technika:</strong><br>
            Rysunek
        </p>

        <p class="description" title="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.        ">
            <strong>Opis:</strong><br>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy t...        
        </p>    
    </div>

</div>
<div id="container-black"></div>
​
```

This code is working in jsfiddle.net: http://jsfiddle.net/MjmDT/1/

It works perfect in chrome, but in FF and IE it's aligned to the left. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: i always thought `zoom` was only for fixing stuff when IE acts up.

Comment: @NullPointer: I don't use jquery in this example. Why are you asking?
@techfoobar: But `zoom` works in chrome. In FF I use different properties. The problem is that it is aligned to the left in strange way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no CSS property named `zoom`. This is a proprietary MS IE extension to CSS (like the `hasLayout` flag).

Additionally, Firefox allows to set what happ3ens on zooming: should the entire page be zoomed into, including any images (default for any current browser version). Or should only text size get increased on zooming the page. Check your Fx-settings: "View" -> "Zoom" (or similar, I have the German version installed).

Comment: But is it possible to scale entire website with css or js? Actually it works, but I don't know why in ff and ie there is that strange align to the left.